# Enable/Disable bluetooth on windows xp c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth

I found [Bluetooth Device Development using C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/09/13/bluetooth-device-control-development-using-c.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&CommentPosted=true#10237561), but what I want, is the code that can control Windows XP Bluetooth. Turning it on or off using C# code.

Answer (score 0):

After short "googling" I found:

```
[DllImport("BthUtil.dll")]
private static extern int BthSetMode(RadioMode dwMode );

[DllImport("BthUtil.dll")]
private static extern int BthGetMode(ref RadioMode dwMode );


/// Bluetooth states.
public enum RadioMode
{
   /// Bluetooth off.
   Off,
   /// Bluetooth is on but not discoverable.
   On,
   /// Bluetooth is on and discoverable.
   Discoverable,
}
```

Don't let the word "radio" mislead you...

If it should run on a desktop pc you can use the [Wireless Communication Library .NET Edition](http://www.btframework.com/download_net.htm)

Comment: but that code only for windows mobile... I need sample code to show Bluetooth enable/disable on my windows xp. i probably hope that code can be used without using windows mobile reference.

Comment: @rose: You are looking for a solution on desktop machines?

Comment: mean on my windows xp on laptop...yes

Comment: @rose: I've added a helpful link for you in my answer.

Comment: The sample trial code have a limitation, it's only can detect Bluetooth on or off in my laptop but don't have capability to turn on or off the Bluetooth.